# Why does 'if a == 40 or 42' evaluate as  'true' when 'a' is 47?

Tags: lua, lua-5.2

I am new to Lua, and trying to get something of this type done in my code, but its not working. Here the syntax and all is absolutely correct, but the elseif condition is going for a toss, and the conditional check is going wrong.

So for this the output that I am getting is: Value = 40 or 42, which is wrong

The Lua version that I am using is 5.2

```
function call(a)
    print (a)
    if a == 40 or 42 then
    print ("Value = 40 or 42")
    elseif a == 43 or 45 then
    print ("Value = 43 or 45")
    elseif a == 46 or 47 then
    print ("Value = 46 or 47")
    end
end

a = 47
call(a)
```

Answer (score 13):

```
if a == 40 or 42 then
```

You want `a` to be compared to both 40 *and* 42, but `==` doesn't work that way. It's a binary operator, it compares two and only two items, so Lua sees your code like this:

```
if (a == 40) or (42) then
```

In Lua, anything that's not `nil` or `false` evaluates as true, so `42` is true in this expression. So what you really wrote is:

```
if (a == 40) or true then
```

Which is the same as:

```
if true then
```

All comparison operators are binary (i.e. two and only two operands), so you want to compare `a` to more than one thing, you'll need to use more than one comparison operator:

```
if (a == 40) or (a == 42) then
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the relational operator wrongly.  `or` takes two arguments. Argument 1 is the relational expression (a==40) and argument 2 is just the number 42 as opposed to (a==42)

You want to do `(a==40) or (a==42)` but what happens is `(a==40) or (42)`

So your code should be:

```
function call(a)
    print (a)
    if a == 40 or a == 42 then
        print ("Value = 40 or 42")
    elseif a == 43 or a == 45 then
        print ("Value = 43 or 45")
    elseif a == 46 or a == 47 then
        print ("Value = 46 or 47")
    end
end

a = 47
call(a)
```

**EDIT**

Sorry. Mud is indeed right.Thanks for pointing that out.
Edited my answer.

Comment: -1: Mud is correct about the precedence; [`or` has *lower* precedence than `==`.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.7)

Comment: @SatheeshJM - Thanks for removing the erroneous information, but your answer now adds nothing beyond what Mud already wrote.

Answer (score 0):

'if 47 == 40 or 42' is a ternary statement. Return true if 47 == 40, and if false, return 42.
Neither 'true' nor '42' are false.

If you want it to return true if a is equal to either 40 or 42, you would write it as:

'if a == 40 or a == 42'